# Scrolling Recycler view with Espresso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have a heterogeneous recycler view and I am trying to scroll it to item at position 30. My test is passing but I cannot see the screen actually scrolling.

```
onView(withId(R.id.content_view))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(30));
```

This is what I am doing to scroll.

Answer (score 13):

Use `scrollToHolder()`:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerViewId))
    .perform(scrollToHolder(viewHolderMatcher(some_parameter_to_match)));
```

where `viewHolderMatcher(some_parameter_to_match)` returns `Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` i.e. the position of the holder/item in the RecyclerView.

Or only by position:

```
onView(withId(rvLayoutId))
    .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(256, scrollTo()));
```

last one is from [here](https://github.com/shauvik/espresso/blob/master/espresso/contrib-tests/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewIntegrationTest.java).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the ViewActions [swipeDown](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#swipeDown())?

Answer (score 2):

Tell it about the ViewHolder.

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview)).perform(
        RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
          YOUR_POSITION
        )
      )
```